# How many comparisons does a max() or a min() function do?

Tags: python, performance, max, time-complexity, min

Given a list of `n` numbers, what is the number of comparison that the `min()` or `max()` function in python does? If this is not optimal, how can I design a function that performs the least comparison?

Comment: Why are you trying to minimize the number of comparisons? I smell an XY problem.

Comment: It should use n-1 comparisons, which is the minimum you can do.

Comment: It should pretty much do `min = l[0]; for i in l[1:]: if i < min: min = i`.

Comment: Or another: `next(iter([i for i in l if not any(x<i for x in l)]))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The built-in `min()` and `max()` iterate over the list once, performing `n-1` comparisons (the first element with the second, then the larger of the first two with the third and so on). This is `O(n)` in [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Unless you know something about your list (such as that it's ordered in a certain way) you can't do better than `O(n)`: any element can be the smallest or the largest and therefore needs to be looked at.

Here is a simplified and annotated version of the loop that's used by both `min()` and `max()`:

```
it = PyObject_GetIter(v); /* v is the list */
maxitem = NULL; /* the result */
maxval = NULL;  /* the value associated with the result, always
                   the same as maxitem in this simplified version */
while (( item = PyIter_Next(it) )) {
    /* maximum value and item are unset; set them */
    if (maxval == NULL) {
        maxitem = item;
        maxval = item;
    }
    /* maximum value and item are set; update them as necessary */
    else {
        int cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(val, maxval, op); /* op is Py_LT or Py_GT */
        if (cmp > 0) {
            maxval = val;
            maxitem = item;
        }
    }
}
```

([source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1583).)

If you need to repeatedly find and remove the smallest, or the largest, element in a collection, and this dominates the runtime of your overall algorithm, it might be worth looking at data structures other than a list.

One data structure that immediately springs to mind is a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). It offers `O(n logn)` insertion and `O(n logn)` removal of the smallest (largest) element. Python has an implementation in its [`heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html).